# Instantiating an object and setting a variable inside an array at the same time

Tags: c#

I want to instantiate an object and change/set a variable inside an array with a short (for efficiency purposes) amount of code, but this doesn't work:

```
    private ClickBox[] clickBoxes = new ClickBox[]
    {
        new ClickBox().OnClick += (@object) =>
        {

        }
    };

class ClickBox
{
    public delegate void ClickEvent(Object @object);

    private ClickEvent clickEvent;

    public ClickEvent OnClick
    {
        get { return clickEvent; }
        set { clickEvent = value; }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know a way to return the object instead of the variable in this code? I know it would work to set the ClickEvent after the array is made, but this would be very inefficient for a large number of items.

Thank you.

Comment: use a builder pattern. this smells.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "(in-)efficient"? The number of code lines mostly doesn't correlate with execution speed. Things like collection- or object initializers are just syntactic sugar, but execute the same operations (setting properties, calling `Add()` etc) when compiled.

Comment: If you regularly need to do the same thing immediately after constructing an object why not create a constructor that actually does what you want?

Comment: Also why are you adding a click event that does nothing?

Comment: No, you can't hook up an event inside the object initializer. You can assign values to the properties in the initializer body, and then hook up the event after the object is created.

Comment: Because the assignment has to be outside the initializer block, you have to do it separately if you want to have a reference to the object you just created, since the event assignment doesn't return anything. (i.e. you could do this, but you have no reference to the Timer afterwards: `new Timer { Interval = 100, Enabled = true }.Elapsed += T_Elapsed;`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really write a builder method to implement this.

Something really simple could look like this:

```
static ClickBox createClickBox(Action<ClickBox> subscribe)
{
    var result = new ClickBox();
    subscribe(result);
    return result;
}
```

You could use that to initialise an array that is a field of the class like so:

```
readonly ClickBox[] clickBoxes =
{
    createClickBox(cb => cb.OnClick += o => { /* Code 1 */ }),
    createClickBox(cb => cb.OnClick += o => { /* Code 2 */ })
};
```

But I must agree with others who say this is a bit of a code smell - although without more context about how you really intend to use this, it's hard to say for sure.

Also, when talking about efficiency: I assume you are talking in terms of reducing the number of lines of code, rather than performance.

Comment: Thank you! You're right when you're saying that I was talking about lines of code, and I'll try to remember to be clearer next time. Sorry for those who were confused.